# why is this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-LEFT', function() {}) not working in phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, phaser-framework

In my sprite sheet I have two separate frames for when the character is not moving, one is for when she was moving left and then stopped and the other for when she was moving right and then stopped, so i need it to fire up on sort of a key up event. I've seen very similar question here, but  the answer didn't work for me, it said to add:

```
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-LEFT', function() 
{
    
});
```

but it just broke my code, screen goes black and nothing happens, i tried adding that code in either `create()` and `update()`
So i tried instead:

```
this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-LEFT', function() 
{
    player.setVelocityX(0);

    player.anims.play('stopLeft');
});
this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-RIGHT', function() 
{
    player.setVelocityX(0);

    player.anims.play('stopRight');
});
```

It doesn't break my code, but also nothing happens, I also tried `player` instead of `scene` or `this`, (`player` is a variable to which my sprite is assigned), but that also broke my code, just like `scene` did.
BTW, `stopLeft` and `stopRight` works fine, because i tested them on normal `this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()` events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to implement player movement and/or input is, to put the logic in the `update` function, and check if the keys are pressed/down (`isDown`).

*I would only use `this.input.keyboard`, for hot-key like 'ESC' or some special hot-keys.*

**Here a short working demo:**
*(for more details checkout [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/games/firstgame/part10#))*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 100 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload,
        create,
        update
    },
    banner: false
};

let player;
let cursor;
let animsKeyText;

function preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'https://labs.phaser.io/src/games/firstgame/assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
    let floor = this.add.rectangle(0, config.height, config.width, 20, 0xcdcdcd)
        .setOrigin(0, .5);

    animsKeyText = this.add.text(10, 10, 'current anims-key: ??')

    this.physics.add.existing(floor, true);

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 10, 'dude')
        .setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'stop-left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 1 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: 0
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'stop-right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 6 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: 0
    });

    this.physics.add.collider(player, floor);

    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(160);
        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        if (player.anims && player.anims.currentAnim) {
            // just to prevent of keys "stop-stop....-right" or so
            if (player.anims.currentAnim.key.indexOf('stop') == -1) {
                let newKey = `stop-${player.anims.currentAnim.key}`;
                player.anims.play(newKey, true);
            }
        }
    }
    if (player.anims && player.anims.currentAnim) {
        animsKeyText.setText(`current anims-key: ${player.anims.currentAnim.key}`);
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: and that's all i was able to find too, but because i wanted specifically to have two differebt frames for when  none of the cursor keys `isDown`, depending on which direction the sprite was moving immediately before the last cursor key was released, so to have just `else { player.setVelocityX(0); player.anims.stopFrame(); }` doesn't work. If i can't do it by having an or release key event, then at least i wish to be able to detect which frame was displayed last, so if it was one of the moving left frames, `stopLeft` would be the next frame, and 'stopRight' if the player was moving right.

Comment: ah, what i did is i deleted the `else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.stop();
    }` part (i was working with the same original code), because i thought i can't just have one final `else` for what i need, but now i put it back and i kept my `this.input.keyboard` statements in `create()` and now the character does exactly what i wanted! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @chylinski I updated my answer to show the two different animation, I hope this helps.

Comment: hi, yep it works, though I don't understand all the syntax, but my sprite sheet is a bit different , frames 0 - 1 are for moving left, 5 - 6 for moving right and 3 is stopLeft, while 4 is stopRight. so the "stop" frames are different to walking frames. Also , why is this approach better to `this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-LEFT', function() 
    {
        player.setVelocityX(0);

        player.anims.play('stopLeft');
    });
    this.input.keyboard.on('keyup-RIGHT', function() 
    {
        player.setVelocityX(0);

        player.anims.play('stopRight');
    });`